# Qt CONFIG -= flat option give strange MSVC project filters

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt, qmake, flat

My C++ project directory structure looks like this :

```
root
  root.pro
  include
    dir1
      header1.h
    dir2
      header2.h
  src
    src.pro
    dir1
      source1.cpp
    dir2
      source2.cpp
```

I'm trying to generate an msvc project using the CONFIG -= flat option to preserve files organisation. This works great for source files (in fact every file in the same directory than the .pro or any deeper directory).

But for my "include" directory, the generated filters are rather strange/stupid !

```
MSVC_project
  Header Files
    ..
      include
        dir1
          header1.h
        dir2
          header2.h
  Source Files
    src1
      source1.cpp
    src2
      source2.cpp
```

Looks like qmake is trying to re-create the directory structure relative to .pro directory.

Feeding the HEADERS and SOURCES qmake variables with relative or absolute file names does not change anything.

My src.pro file, nothing fancy :

```
NAME = proj_name
TEMPLATE = lib
CONFIG -= flat
QT += core gui opengl
ROOTDIR = ..
#ROOTDIR = $$system(cygpath -aw ../..)

HEADERS_PATH = $$ROOTDIR/include

INCLUDEPATH += $$HEADERS_PATH
HEADERS += $$system(find $$HEADERS_PATH -name "*.h")
SOURCES += $$system(find . -name "*.cpp")
...
```

Any idea how I can tell qmake to generate proper filters ?